# Using /container/id/top command for docker api

Tags: api, docker

I am quite new to docker, but already impressed about its capability!

One question I have is when I run the /container/id/top api, I got some attributes value back, but not as the ones I see in documentation.

From [docker remote API documents](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.13/#21-containers), I see:
List processes running inside a container
GET /containers/(id)/top

List processes running inside the container id

**Example request**:

```
GET /containers/4fa6e0f0c678/top HTTP/1.1
```

**Example response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
     "Titles":[
             "USER",
             "PID",
             "%CPU",
             "%MEM",
             "VSZ",
             "RSS",
             "TTY",
             "STAT",
             "START",
             "TIME",
             "COMMAND"
             ],
     "Processes":[
             ["root","20147","0.0","0.1","18060","1864","pts/4","S","10:06","0:00","bash"],
             ["root","20271","0.0","0.0","4312","352","pts/4","S+","10:07","0:00","sleep","10"]
     ]
}
```

But when I run the same api on my dock enabled VM, I got

```
"Processes": [
    [
        "root",
        "27467",
        "1449",
        "0",
        "19:39",
        "pts/3",
        "00:00:00",
        "/bin/bash"
    ],
    [
        "root",
        "28010",
        "27467",
        "0",
        "19:46",
        "pts/3",
        "00:11:03",
        "/bin/bash"
    ]
],
"Titles": [
    "UID",
    "PID",
    "PPID",
    "C",
    "STIME",
    "TTY",
    "TIME",
    "CMD"
]
```

which doesn't contain the cpu and mem %. Is there anything I need to enable?

My docker version is 
suse64:~ # docker version
Client version: 1.1.1
Client API version: 1.13
Go version (client): go1.3
Git commit (client): dc62f3c
Server version: 1.1.1
Server API version: 1.13
Go version (server): go1.3
Git commit (server): dc62f3c

Thanks a lot in advance.
Enlin

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. However, the man pages differ from the online documentation and don't reflect the cpu and memory utilization. Have you found the solution or an workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to `?ps_args=-aux` argument to the query. For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.10/containers/<contained_id>/top?ps_args=-aux
```

This should return the cpu and memory statistics for all processes in a json object.

Source: [Similar issues on github](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7205)